# Less files not working with AEM

Tags: css, less, aem, day-cq

I am upgrading my website from CQ 5.5.1 to AEM 5.6 and the less parser is failing and it does not compile less files to CSS. Any suggestions of a possible fix to solve the issue.

Comment: Please provide as much information as possible about your problem, for example when the less parser fails, does it generate an error message?

Comment: Are you using any maven-plugin to compile less files?

Answer (score 2):

I came across this scenario recently where there was issue with less files not getting compiling adn was getting **(uncompiled LESS src is included below)**
Rebuilding the clientlibs solved this issue and the error was gone and the styles where loading correctly.

**Steps**

Go to /libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.rebuild.html
and invalidate the cache and rebuild the libs

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

this link can be usefull: http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__ibm7-hi_we_are_moving.html

The thing is, in AEM 5.6.1 LESS compiler was updated to 1.3.3 and also the approach to server-side compilation was changed: prior to 5.6.1, your clientlib (including all embeds) was passed to LESS compiler as a single concatenated file.

Starting with 5.6.1, each LESS file in your clientlib is compiled separately, that is why the compilation will fail, in case you had your variable declarations in a separate file which was then embedded into numerous clientlibs. This leads to the following error (can be found in produced css):

```
/*****************************************************
LESS compilation failed due a JavaScript error!

Input: /etc/designs/widget.less
Error: @myVar is undefined

(uncompiled LESS src is included below)
*****************************************************/
```

To solve this issue, use @Import statement, which is now supported.